# ms sql select procedure content from row number

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a task to obtain data from stored procedure. 
This is not difficult: `EXEC sp_helptext N'Title.Procedure'`
the result is one column 'text' that contains text of procedure.

But the problem is how to read content of procedure on row number @num
I tried to add index to result query, but in this case the text of procedure is ordered.

Is there  some way fr to read text for example from row number = 123 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
    myId int identity(1,1),
    Val VARCHAR(max)
)

INSERT INTO @Table EXEC sp_helptext N'Title.Procedure'

select Val from @Table where myId = 123
```

basically you put the output of sp_helptext in a table variable with an identity column so that you can select the row you want (in the example row 123)